# Search input bar layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I'm trying to use a lightning input type search to make a search bar that I will connect to a database to search throught all my items (but this is not the problem)
I would like to show the search bar like the one in the photo below, but with my code i can't see the "some text center align" white and centered, can anyone help me?

[image: what i would like to show]

this is my code:

```
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
        <lightning-input type="search" label="some text center align" placeholder="search something"></lightning-input>
    </div>
```

CSS:

.lgc-bg {
background-color: green;
text-align: center;
}

JS:

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class InputText extends LightningElement {}

with my code I have this result (doent't matter the shade of green):

[image: my output:]

so: how can I make the "some text center align" white and the search symbol right and not left?
thank everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`lightning-` namespace'd components are limited to exposed attributes and styling hooks due to shadow DOM, you are better off creating an input component of type search, and customizing it from scratch.